# Showing form input on submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form with one input field and when I press `enter` I would like to see this input written under the form. I would like to have as many inputs as possible, each new one to be displayed under the previous one.

I tried it like this but I failed.

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="" value="" id="form-input">
</form>
<ul>
  <li id="form-list"></li>
</ul>
```

And then inside my `<script>` tag:

```
var formInput = document.getElementById("form-input")
var formOutput = document.getElementById("form-list")
formOutput.innerHTML = formInput.value;
formInput.onsubmit = function() {
  formOutput.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

When I press `enter` it refreshes the page, if I change `onsubmit` to `oninput` it displays what I'm writing but it is not saved.

Is it possible to display multiple inputs like this? Thanks

Comment: are you limited on the client side? you may need a server side scripting like PHP or ASP.net you can learn it here https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: that's what i feared. at the moment i'm only limited to client side.

Comment: Do you want to dynamically generate `input` elements in the list every time someone enters something in the top level `input` element?

Comment: In your onsubmit handler just add parameter e, and add `e.preventDefault()` or return false to prevent the form submission.  I may be misunderstanding what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly but here is one way to listen for the 'enter' key press on an input element and create a dynamic list of input elements with the entered value.

```js
var inputEl = document.getElementById("in");
var targetList = document.getElementById("list");

function createItem(text){
  var listItem = document.createElement('li');
  var input  = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'text';
  input.value = text;
  listItem.appendChild(input);
  targetList.appendChild(listItem);
}

inputEl.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    createItem(inputEl.value);
    inputEl.value = '';
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="in" type="text" name="" value="">
</form>
<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

> When I press enter it refreshes the page, if I change onsubmit to
>   oninput it displays what I'm writing but it is not saved.

You can use **cookies** to store and persist data on every refresh

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

or **WebStorage/Application Storage**

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

But I really advise that learn to use server-side scripting with a database so your data will have permanent persistence across browser sessions

https://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code run with these changes in HTML and your Javascript:

```js
var formInput = document.getElementById("form-input")
var formOutput = document.getElementById("form-list")

function AddElement() {
  var NewValue = formInput.value;
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var text = document.createTextNode(NewValue);
  li.appendChild(text);
  formOutput.appendChild(li);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return AddElement();">
  <input type="text" name="" value="" id="form-input">
</form>
<ul id="form-list"></ul>
```